# Xero API organisation connections

Tags: xero-api

I have more than a 1000 organisations(my clients) to connect to and I am only able to give it access one by one, can someone please tell me how do I add all the organisations at once?

Thanks :)

I tried to do it one by one and i think there should be a better way of doing thsi as I had to generate a new access token to add each organisation, there should be some method to add them all together at once.

Comment: AFAIK an auth token only gives you access to a single organisation.